# body isn't getting loaded with php

Tags: php, html

My Website works normal, but when I try to use it with my php code everything loads normal exept the body. So the page is empty.
I don't know what to do.
My php code:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("todo.json", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$json = fread($myfile,filesize("todo.json"));
$obj = json_decode($json);
$jsonend = (array)$obj;
fclose($myfile);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$what = $_POST['whatis'];
$changeto = $_POST['wantedtochangeto'];

$filewrite = fopen("todo.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$jsonend[$what] = $changeto;
$jsonendwrite = json_encode($jsonend);

fwrite($filewrite, $jsonendwrite);
fclose($filewrite);
};
```

I tried exluding the php and erverything works normal

Comment: can you provide an example of what your todo.json looks like?

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. I tried to require my php. I just wrote my php inside the inde.php now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).